# Split one file into multiple files based on pattern

Tags: bash, sed, split, awk

I have a binary file which I convert into a regular file using hexdump and few awk and sed commands. The output file looks something like this -

```
$cat temp
3d3d01f87347545002f1d5b2be4ee4d700010100018000cc57e5820000000000000000000
000000087d3f513000000000000000000000000000000000001001001010f000000000026 
58783100b354c52658783100b43d3d0000ad6413400103231665f301010b9130194899f2f
fffffffffff02007c00dc015800a040402802f1d5b2b8ca5674504f433031000000000004
6363070000000000000000000000000065450000b4fb6b4000393d3d1116cdcc57e58287d
3f55285a1084b
```

The temp file has few eye catchers (3d3d) which don't repeat that often. They kinda denote a start of new binary record. I need to split the file based on those eye catchers.

My desired output is to have multiple files (based on the number of eyecatchers in my temp file).

So my output would look something like this -

```
$cat temp1
3d3d01f87347545002f1d5b2be4ee4d700010100018000cc57e582000000000000000
0000000000087d3f513000000000000000000000000000000000001001001010f00000000
002658783100b354c52658783100b4

$cat temp2
3d3d0000ad6413400103231665f301010b9130194899f2ffffffffffff02007c00dc0
15800a040402802f1d5b2b8ca5674504f4330310000000000046363070000000000000000
000000000065450000b4fb6b400039

$cat temp3
3d3d1116cdcc57e58287d3f55285a1084b
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;
$_ = <>;
$n = 0;

for $match (split(/(?=3d3d)/)) {
      open(O, '>temp' . ++$n);
      print O $match;
      close(O);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great and I can call this script within my parser script before running the parser code so that it runs on all the temp files.

Comment: Any suggestions on which book should I pick up for learning Perl. I am new to UNIX and have recently started learning bash, sed and awk.

Comment: Usage: Copy into new file split.pl then make it executable and run: `./split.pl yourdata.txt`

Comment: @rob-mayoff can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671047/split-big-file-in-unix-based-on-size-and-pattern

Answer (score 21):

The `RS` variable in `awk` is nice for this, allowing you to define the record separator. Thus, you just need to capture each record in its own temp file. The simplest version is:

```
cat temp |
  awk -v RS="3d3d" '{ print $0 > "temp" NR }'
```

The sample text starts with the eye-catcher `3d3d`, so temp1 will be an empty file. Further, the eye-catcher itself won't be at the start of the temp files, as was shown for the temp files in the question. Finally, if there are a lot of records, you could run into the system limit on open files. Some minor complications will bring it closer to what you want and make it safer:

```
cat temp |
  awk -v RS="3d3d" 'NR > 1 { print RS $0 > "temp" (NR-1); close("temp" (NR-1)) }'
```

Comment: Khm, you don't need `cat` for that. And if it's a single line input  you will only get the first record. And the output will miss the original `RS` as well. `echo '3d3dsomething3d3danything' | awk 'BEGIN {RS="3d3d"} {print}'` will only output `something`.

Comment: Or I was wrong. The only problem with your solution is missing the `RS` in the output. (And the useless use of `cat`.)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai RS is in the output, as discussed. And cat is not useless: it provides a logical separation between generation of data and processing. Thus, `cat temp` stands in for whatever transformations go on before the awk stage, while avoiding adding even more to the already long line with awk.

Comment: You are right, sorry about the `RS` part. Regarding `cat`, you might want to read this: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai Well aware of it, although not convinced that it says anything relevant about the appropriate rhetorical exposition. You might want to read the other view in, e.g., *Classic Shell Scripting* (Robbins and Beebe, 2005).

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Sorry, I didn't quite get how would `3d3d` get in the output files since the `ORS` variable has not been set. Can you please explain whenever you get a chance. I have posted a solution too now that I am little familiar with `awk`.

Comment: @JaypalSingh The first version doesn't have the `3d3d`, and has the shortcomings discussed in the text. The second version is the more complete. In it, the `print` statement includes an explicit `RS`, which is `3d3d`. This is the same thing you did in your solution.

Answer (score 5):

This might work:

```
# sed 's/3d3d/\n&/2g' temp | split -dl1 - temp
# ls
temp temp00  temp01  temp02
# cat temp00
3d3d01f87347545002f1d5b2be4ee4d700010100018000cc57e5820000000000000000000000000087d3f513000000000000000000000000000000000001001001010f000000000026 58783100b354c52658783100b4
# cat temp01
3d3d0000ad6413400103231665f301010b9130194899f2ffffffffffff02007c00dc015800a040402802f1d5b2b8ca5674504f4330310000000000046363070000000000000000000000000065450000b4fb6b400039
# cat temp02
3d3d1116cdcc57e58287d3f55285a1084b
```

EDIT:

If there are newlines in the source file you can remove them first by using `tr -d '\n' <temp` and then pipe the output through the above `sed` command. If however you wish to preserve them then:

```
 sed 's/3d3d/\n&/g;s/^\n\(3d3d\)/\1/' temp |csplit -zf temp - '/^3d3d/' {*}
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Just to remark that the effect of the combined flags `2g` to sed's `s` command is not standardized. The author expects GNU sed's behaviour :  For GNU 'sed', the interaction is
     defined to be: ignore matches before the NUMBERth, and then match
     and replace all matches from the NUMBERth on.

Answer (score 0):

## Mac OS X answer

Where that nice `awk -v RS="pattern"` trick doesn't work. Here's what I got working:

Given this example `concatted.txt`

```
filename=foo bar
foo bar line1
foo bar line2
filename=baz qux
baz qux line1
baz qux line2
```

use this command (remove comments to prevent it from failing)

```bash
# cat: useless use of cat ^__^;
# tr: replace all newlines with delimiter1 (which must not be in concatted.txt) so we have one line of all the next
# sed: replace file start pattern with delimiter2 (which must not be in concatted.txt) so we know where to split out each file
# tr: replace delimiter2 with NULL character since sed can't do it
# xargs: split giant single-line input on NULL character and pass 1 line (= 1 file) at a time to echo into the pipe
# sed: get all but last line (same as head -n -1) because there's an extra since concatted-file.txt ends in a NULL character.
# awk: does a bunch of stuff as the final command. Remember it's getting a single line to work with.
#   {replace all delimiter1s in file with newlines (in place)}
#   {match regex (sets RSTART and RLENGTH) then set filename to regex match (might end at delimiter1). Note in this case the number 9 is the length of "filename=" and the 2 removes the "§" }
#   {write file to filename and close the file (to avoid "too many files open" error)}
cat ../concatted-file.txt \
| tr '\n' '§' \
| sed 's/filename=/∂filename=/g' \
| tr '∂' '\0' \
| xargs -t -0 -n1 echo \
| sed \$d \
| awk '{match($0, /filename=[^§]+§/)} {filename=substr($0, RSTART+9, RLENGTH-9-2)".txt"} {gsub(/§/, "\n", $0)} {print $0 > filename; close(filename)}'
```

results in these two files named `foo bar.txt` and `baz qux.txt` respectively:

```
filename=foo bar
foo bar line1
foo bar line2
```

```
filename=baz qux
baz qux line1
baz qux line2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

It depends if it's a single line in your `temp` file or not. But assuming if it's a single line, you can go with:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\(3d3d\)/\1#\2/g' FILE | awk -F "#" '{ for (i=1; i++; i<=NF) { print $i > "temp" i } }'
```

The first `sed` inserts a `#` as a field/record separator, then `awk` splits on `#` and prints every "field" to its own file.

If the input file is already split on `3d3d` then you can go with:

```
awk '/^3d3d/ { i++ } { print > "temp" i }' temp
```

HTH