# awk split on hex string

Tags: bash, awk, hex, jpeg

I have a file with multiple jpegs inside. So i would like to split them to single jpegs.

The easy part is to find the beginning: `0xFF0xD8 0xFF0xE1` marks the beginning of the JPG and the EXIF Data field, which is in my case always at the beginning.

So I found this awk command:

`awk '/string/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt`

To split the files. Which does not work as expected when I use it with hex:

`awk '/0xFF0xD8 0xFF0xE1/{n++}{print >"out" n ".txt" }' final.txt`

The doc of awk says that all strings with 0x in front are used as hex but I seems not working well..

Edit: well i found this: https://superuser.com/questions/174362/how-to-split-binary-file-based-on-pattern but it does not work for me... it should create 2 files, but only one is created and its only 11 Bytes big

Comment: `0x` is the beginning of a text representation of an hex value. But if your file is binary, you won't find it.

Comment: Does JFIF guarentee not to have this sequence anywhere else?

Comment: no i doesnt but i could add some more bytes to the search sequence and it would be sufficant enough for my task

Comment: I think the first bytes should be `FF D8 FF E0`

Comment: The doc of awk says that all strings with \0x in front are used as hex.

Comment: what? i read there `0x` and not `\0x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure awk handles binary files well? I thought it would expect newlines.

Perl can use hex escapes in regexes (Basic idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061558/381281)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
undef $/;
$_ = <>;
$n = 0;
for $content (split(/(?=\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0)/)) {
        open(OUT, ">out" . ++$n . ".txt");
        print OUT $content;
        close(OUT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perl if probably the preferred tool, but awk can handle it just fine:

```
awk '{print > "out" NR ".jpg"}' RS=$( printf '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0' )
```