# Split one file into multiple files based on pattern (cut can occur within lines)

Tags: python, perl, awk, split, gnu

A lot of solutions exist, but the specificity here is I need to be able to split within a line, the cut should occur just before the pattern. Ex:

Infile:

```
<?xml 1><blabla1>
<blabla><blabla2><blabla>
<blabla><blabla>
<blabla><blabla3><blabla><blabla>
<blabla><blabla><blabla><?xml 4>
<blabla>
<blabla><blabla><blabla>
<blabla><?xml 2><blabla><blabla>
```

Should become with pattern `<?xml`

Outfile1:

```
<?xml 1><blabla1>
<blabla><blabla2><blabla>
<blabla><blabla>
<blabla><blabla3><blabla><blabla>
<blabla><blabla><blabla>
```

Outfile2:

```
<?xml 4>
<blabla>
<blabla><blabla><blabla>
<blabla>
```

Outfile3:

```
<?xml 2><blabla><blabla>
```

Actually the `perl` script in the validated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061475/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern) works fine for my little example. But it generates an error for my bigger (about 6GB) actual files. The error is:

```
panic: sv_setpvn called with negative strlen at /home/.../split.pl line 7, <> chunk 1.
```

I don't have the permissions to comment, that's why I started a new post.
And finally, a `Python` solution would be even more appreciated, as I understand it better.

Comment: not a perl solution, but based on awk and does the job:` awk -v RS="<?xml" '{print RS $0 > "Outfile"(NR-1)}' Infile `.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This performs the split without reading everything into RAM:

```
def files():
    n = 0
    while True:
        n += 1
        yield open('/output/dir/%d.part' % n, 'w')


pat = '<?xml'
fs = files()
outfile = next(fs) 

with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if pat not in line:
            outfile.write(line)
        else:
            items = line.split(pat)
            outfile.write(items[0])
            for item in items[1:]:
                outfile = next(fs)
                outfile.write(pat + item)
```

A word of warning: this doesn't work if your pattern spreads across multiple lines (that is, contains "\n"). Consider the [mmap solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717534/989121) if this is the case.

Comment: Easy to understand and pretty efficient. Thanks!

Comment: OK. That's not my case. The only (minor) issue is that it creates a 1st empty file.

Answer (score 7):

Perl can parse large files line by line instead of slurping the whole file into memory.
Here is a short script (with explanation):

```
perl -n -E 'if (/(.*)(<\?xml.*)/ ) {
   print $fh $1 if $1;
   open $fh, ">output." . ++$i;
   print $fh $2;
} else { print $fh $_ }'  in.txt
```

`perl -n` : The *-n* flag will loop over your file line by line (setting the contents to $_)

`-E` : Execute the following text (Perl expects a filename by default)

`if (/(.*)(<\?xml.*) )` if a line matches `<?xml` split that line (using regex matchs) into $1  and $2.

`print $fh $1 if $1` Print the start of the line to the old file.

`open $fh, ">output.". ++$i;` Create a new file-handle for writing.

`print $fh $2` Print the rest of the line to the new file.

`} else { print $fn $_ }` If the line didn't match `<?xml` just print it to the current file-handle.

Note: this script assumes your input file starts with `<?xml`.

Answer (score 6):

For files of that size, you'll probably want to use the [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module, so you don't have to handle chunking up the file yourself. From the docs there:

> Memory-mapped file objects behave like both strings and like file
>   objects. Unlike normal string objects, however, these are mutable. You
>   can use mmap objects in most places where strings are expected; for
>   example, you can use the re module to search through a memory-mapped
>   file. Since they’re mutable, you can change a single character by
>   doing `obj[index] = 'a'`, or change a substring by assigning to a slice:
>   `obj[i1:i2] = '...'`. You can also read and write data starting at the
>   current file position, and `seek()` through the file to different
>   positions.

Here's a quick example that shows you how to find each occurrence of `<?xml #>` in the file.  You can write the chunks to new files as you go, but I haven't written that part.

```
import mmap
import re

# a regex to match the "xml" nodes
r = re.compile(r'\<\?xml\s\d+\>')

with open('so.txt','r+b') as f:
    mp = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    for m in r.finditer(mp):
        # here you can start collecting the starting positions and 
        # writing chunks to new files 
        print m.start()
```

Comment: I like this solution, it seems very clever. As I have to process it in a python program which does something with the split files, I guess I could give it a list of mmap instead of files. My only problem is it's a bit hard to handle, not so simple.

Answer (score 0):

just do a split on your search terms

```
for i,part in enumerate(my_xml_Text_string.split("<?xml")):
    if not part.strip():continue # make sure its not empty
    with open("file%d.xml"%i,"w") as f: #open a file to write to
         f.write("<?xml"+part) #write the content putting your search term back in
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. This answer appears in the "low quality posts" list.

Comment: I hope you're not suggesting my_xml_Text_string will contain a 6GB string?

Comment: yeah I guess my selective vision skipped that part of the memo :P