# generator 'yield' in splitting structured input file produces out of sync result

Tags: python, xml, parsing, generator

Referring to the top answer by @georg (which I've adapted below) here:
[Split one file into multiple files based on pattern (cut can occur within lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717294/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-cut-can-occur-within-lines)

I find this a potentially useful pattern to split a file into multiples, based on the initial delimiter.
However, as a commenter notes, it creates a blank file first, the reason for which is unclear. I think this is related to the problem I'm having.

In my (clumsy, I'm no python master!) adaptation, I try to set the filename  by parsing the line following the delimiter before opening the new output file by calling the output=next(fs) generator.

However, the dilemma, of course, is that the domain name is not known until the line after the delimiter. I end up with filenames which are one step out of sync with the contained data.

The input file contains 100+ `xml` 'trees', each of which starts with a standard

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

followed by a line like this which includes the domain name

```
<ns2:domain ... name="atypi.org" ...">
```

Here is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import re

def files():
    n = 0 
    while n<12 :
         n += 1
         print "**DEBUG** in generator nameFile=%s n=%d \r" % (nameFile, n) 
         yield open('/Users/peterf/Google Drive/2015 Projects-Strategy/Domain Admin/RackDomains/%s.part.xml' % nameFile, 'w')


filename='/Users/peterf/Google Drive/2015 Projects-Strategy/Domain Admin/RackspaceListDomain.output.xml'
nameFile=''
pat ='<?xml'
namePat=re.compile('<ns2:domain.+ name="(.+?)".+>')
fs = files()
outfile = next(fs)

with open(filename) as infile:
     for line in infile:   
        m=namePat.search(line)
        if m:
           nameFile=m.group(1)
           print "<---\rin 'if m:' nameFile=%s\r" % (nameFile)   
        if pat not in line: 
#           print "\rin 'pat not in line' line=%s\r" % (line)       
           outfile.write(line)
        else:
            items = line.split(pat)
            outfile.write(items[0])
            for item in items[1:]:
                print "in 'for item' pre next(fs) nameFile=%s\r" % (nameFile)
                outfile = next(fs)
                print "in 'for item' post next(fs) nameFile=%s --->\r" % (nameFile)
                outfile.write(pat + item)
```

My debug listing shows:

```
**DEBUG** in generator nameFile= n=1 

in 'for item' pre next(fs) nameFile=

**DEBUG** in generator nameFile= n=2 

in 'for item' post next(fs) nameFile= --->

<---
in 'if m:' nameFile=addressing.com

in 'for item' pre next(fs) nameFile=addressing.com

**DEBUG** in generator nameFile=addressing.com n=3 

in 'for item' post next(fs) nameFile=addressing.com --->

<---
in 'if m:' nameFile=alicemcmahon.com

in 'for item' pre next(fs) nameFile=alicemcmahon.com

**DEBUG** in generator nameFile=alicemcmahon.com n=4 

in 'for item' post next(fs) nameFile=alicemcmahon.com --->

<---
in 'if m:' nameFile=alphabets.com

in 'for item' pre next(fs) nameFile=alphabets.com

**DEBUG** in generator nameFile=alphabets.com n=5 

in 'for item' post next(fs) nameFile=alphabets.com --->
```

the output directory contains these filenames, beginning with a truncated name from the first 'yield' I guess...

```
.part.xml (this has data from 'addressing.com')
addressing.com.part.xml
alicemcmahon.com.part.xml
alphabets.com.part.xml
americanletterpress.com.part.xml
americanwoodtype.com.part.xml
amyshoemaker.com.part.xml
archaicrevivalbooks.com.part.xml
archaicrevivalfonts.com.part.xml
archaicrevivalimages.com.part.xml
astroteddies.com.part.xml
```

I can't figure out how to approach this problem, where the generator is producing an output file before I can get an appropriate name for the file.

Here's some representative sections of the input file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ns2:domain xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/v1.0" xmlns="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/management/v1.0" id="1204245"  name="addressing.com" ttl="300" emailAddress="ipadmin@stabletransit.com" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:36Z" created="2009-07-25T15:05:39Z">
    <ns2:nameservers>
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns1.stabletransit.com" />
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns2.stabletransit.com" />
    </ns2:nameservers>
    <ns2:recordsList totalEntries="5">
        <ns2:record id="A-2542579" type="A" name="addressing.com" data="198.101.155.141" ttl="300" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:35Z" created="2010-02-17T05:02:16Z" />
    </ns2:recordsList>
</ns2:domain>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:domain xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/v1.0" xmlns="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/management/v1.0" id="2776403"  name="alicemcmahon.com" ttl="300" emailAddress="ipadmin@stabletransit.com" updated="2013-10-21T16:43:17Z" created="2011-05-01T03:01:51Z">
    <ns2:nameservers>
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns1.stabletransit.com" />
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns2.stabletransit.com" />
    </ns2:nameservers>
    <ns2:recordsList totalEntries="10">
        <ns2:record id="A-6895108" type="A" name="alicemcmahon.com" data="216.185.152.144" ttl="300" updated="2013-10-21T16:43:17Z" created="2011-05-01T03:01:51Z" />
    </ns2:recordsList>
</ns2:domain>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:domain xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/v1.0" xmlns="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/management/v1.0" id="1204247"  name="americanletterpress.com" ttl="300" emailAddress="ipadmin@stabletransit.com" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:37Z" created="2009-07-25T15:05:41Z">
    <ns2:nameservers>
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns1.stabletransit.com" />
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns2.stabletransit.com" />
    </ns2:nameservers>
    <ns2:recordsList totalEntries="5">
        <ns2:record id="A-2542581" type="A" name="americanletterpress.com" data="198.101.155.141" ttl="300" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:36Z" created="2010-02-17T05:02:16Z" />        
    </ns2:recordsList>
</ns2:domain>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:domain xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/v1.0" xmlns="http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/dns/api/management/v1.0" id="1204249"  name="americanwoodtype.com" ttl="300" emailAddress="ipadmin@stabletransit.com" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:38Z" created="2009-07-25T15:05:42Z">
    <ns2:nameservers>
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns1.stabletransit.com" />
        <ns2:nameserver name="dns2.stabletransit.com" />
    </ns2:nameservers>
    <ns2:recordsList totalEntries="5">
        <ns2:record id="A-2542583" type="A" name="americanwoodtype.com" data="198.101.155.141" ttl="300" updated="2012-10-10T21:33:37Z" created="2010-02-17T05:02:16Z" />
    </ns2:recordsList>
</ns2:domain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the generator to produce an output file at the very start:

```
nameFile=''
# ...
outfile = next(fs)
```

That's your blank filename right there. Postpone calling `next(fs)` until you have a value for `nameFile`, and not before.

You could set `outfile = None` instead and test for `None` before you write:

```
if pat not in line:
    if outfile is not None: 
        outfile.write(line)
else:
    items = line.split(pat)
    if outfile is not None:
        outfile.write(items[0])
```

If you need to handle lines before you can find your first filename, store those lines in a buffer instead, and clear the buffer when you first create a new file.

Not that I think you should be using a generator **at all**, you are really overcomplicating things by using one. Just create new file objects *directly in your loop*, that's much clearer.

If all you are doing is split the file, use a buffer until you have a filename:

```
buffer = []
out_name = '/Users/peterf/Google Drive/2015 Projects-Strategy/Domain Admin/RackDomains/%s.part.xml'

outfile = None

with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # look for a filename to write to if we don't have one yet
        if outfile is None:
            match = namePat.search(line)
            if match:
                # New filename, open a file object
                outfile = open(out_name % match.group(1), 'w')
                # clear out the buffer, we'll write directly to 
                # the file after this.
                outfile.writelines(buffer)
                buffer = []

        if '<?xml' in line:
            # new XML doc, close off the previous one
            if outfile is not None:
                outfile.close()
            outfile = None

        # line handling
        if outfile is None:
            buffer.append(line)
        else:
            outfile.write(line)

if outfile is not None:
    outfile.close()
# All lines processed, if there is a buffer left, then we have unhandled lines
if buffer:
    print('There were trailing lines without a name')
    print(*buffer, sep='')
```

Comment: Thanks @martijn! I will revise my approach. It was good to learn about generators, in any case ;-)

Comment: Very useful indeed! And was my question worth a +1? ;-)
As you can see I'm barely getting started here, even though I built my first website in 1992! 
https://web-beta.archive.org/web/19970708013523/http://www.alphabets.com:80/

Comment: @pfraterdeus: and I believe you printed our business cards (I used to be a part of Jarn)! Just hang in there, perseverance is rewarded in the long run.

Comment: Of course! I knew your name was familiar from the Ploniverse ;-)
Thanks again for the tips... It always seems so simple and straightforward when it's laid out in front of me!
This little project has also raised my understanding of XSLT substantially (it seems really silly to me that there's not an open format standard for DNS record interchange, but it's been a good exercise to transform the Rackspace export format to OpenSRS import!)