# splitting a huge text file based on line content

Tags: bash, awk, sed, split, csplit

Help me guys, I'm really lost here.
I have a big text file, full of links, and I'm trying to separate them based on which website the link belongs. I was trying to do it with the csplit command, but I'm not really sure how I would do it, as it would depend on the text content.

Text example:

```
www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/csplit/&hl=en
www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/126539-csplit-help.html/RK=0/RS=iGOr1SINnK126qZciYPZtBHpEmg-
www.w3cschool.cc/linux/linux-comm-csplit.html
www.linuxdevcenter.com/cmd/cmd.csp?path=c/csplit+"csplit"&hl=en&ct=clnk
```

So in this example the first two links would be in one file, and the 2 left would be in one file each.
How would this work? I really don't have any idea if this is even possible. (novice programmer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split one file into multiple files based on pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061475/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print > $1}' [your file name]
```

output:

```
cat www.unix.com 
www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/csplit/&hl=en
www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/126539-csplit-help.html/RK=0/RS=iGOr1SINnK126qZciYPZtBHpEmg-
cat www.linuxdevcenter.com 
www.linuxdevcenter.com/cmd/cmd.csp?path=c/csplit+"csplit"&hl=en&ct=clnk
cat www.w3cschool.cc 
www.w3cschool.cc/linux/linux-comm-csplit.html
```

`{print > $1}` will redirect output to separate files based on `$1`, in this case, the domain name.

Comment: Or just `awk -F/ '{print > $1}' file`

Comment: oh. I don't know this could be set in arguments. could multiple separator defined in this way?

Comment: Yes: `-F"[a-c]"` or `-F"this|that"` or any regex `-F"([0-9]+|[a-b])|more"`

Comment: Thanks you both, it worked flawlessly! I had http:// at the start of each line and I also had some empty lines, but nothing that 'sed' didn't take care of.