# Split big file in unix based on size and pattern

Tags: linux, sed, split

I have a huge file, 45 GB. I want to split it into 4 parts. I can do this by: `split --bytes=12G inputfile`.

Problem is it disturbs the pattern of the file. This split cut the file based on size so format is not preserved. My input file looks like this:

```
Inspecting sequence ID   chr1:11873-13873

 V$ARID3A_04            |     1981 (-) |  0.899 |  0.774 | tttctatAATAActaaa
 V$ARID3A_04            |     1982 (+) |  0.899 |  0.767 | ttctaTAATAactaaag
Inspecting sequence ID   chr1:11873-13873

 V$ARID3A_04            |     1981 (-) |  0.899 |  0.774 | tttctatAATAActaaa
 V$ARID3A_04            |     1982 (+) |  0.899 |  0.767 | ttctaTAATAactaaag
```

I want to split the file but also mention mention the pattern that split it at `Inspecting` so that splitted files I get back must look like this:

```
Inspecting sequence ID   chr1:11873-13873

 V$ARID3A_04            |     1981 (-) |  0.899 |  0.774 | tttctatAATAActaaa
 V$ARID3A_04            |     1982 (+) |  0.899 |  0.767 | ttctaTAATAactaaag
 V$ARNT_Q6_01           |      390 (+) |  1.000 |  0.998 | tACGTGgc
```

and this:

```
Inspecting sequence ID   chr1:11873-13873

 V$ARID3A_04            |     1981 (-) |  0.899 |  0.774 | tttctatAATAActaaa
 V$ARID3A_04            |     1982 (+) |  0.899 |  0.767 | ttctaTAATAactaaag
 V$ARNT_Q6_01           |      390 (+) |  1.000 |  0.998 | tACGTGgc
```

`NOTE:` This pattern matching should be a second preference while first should be the size. For example, split files into chuncks of 12 GB and split based on pattern match of `Inspecting`. If I do split just based on pattern `Inspecting` then I will get thousands of splitted file because this pattern is repeating again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doint it with `sed` would be pretty difficult, since you have no easy way of keeping track of the characters read so far. It would be easier with `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    fileno = 1
}
{
    size += length()
}
size > 100000 && /Inspecting/ {
    fileno++
    size = 0
}
{
    print $0 > "out" fileno;
}
```

Adjust the size according to your needs. `awk`might have problems handling very large numbers. For this reason it might be better to keep track of the number of lines read so far.

Comment: Can you please explain if 100000 is the no.of the lines to read then on next "inspecting" break it and then it becomes the part of next output file? Secondly, is fileno the input file name here?

Comment: `fileno` is part of the output file name, and the size is calculated in characters, not lines. It adds up the string length of all input lines.

Comment: where are you reading the input file here? Sorry for my naivety, I am a newbie to linux OS

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your intention...? I do not use `split`. I split the original file directly.

Comment: I want original file to be intact (size 45 GB) and then make 4 new chunks of 12 GB. I think I'll do it by `awk -f process.awk inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt`. where process.awk contains the code you mentioned above, am I right?