# Sort and split CSV file using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a CSV file (test.csv) that looks like this:

```
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,1221-ESD
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-21
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A101,PWR-120
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A1,074-HD-SATA
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,PWR-120
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A15,102-55665
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-20
WH_03,TRAINLON,UK-B3,101859
```

1). I can sort the file based on the value in column# 2 as follows:

```
sort -t, -k2,2 test.csv > testsort.csv
```

2). Next I would like to split the file based on the value in column# 2. Using the above example, it should create 3 files:

```
testsort_1.csv:
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,1221-ESD
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A101,PWR-120
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,PWR-120

testsort_2.csv:
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A1,074-HD-SATA
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A15,102-55665

testsort_3.csv:
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-20
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-21
WH_03,TRAINLON,UK-B3,101859
```

How can I do this? Not sure if the sort is even required and if the above can be achieved without sorting.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you feel about `grep`?

Comment: And do you want to specify the map (e.g. `TRAINAMS` -> `testsort_1.cv`), or do you want the script to work it out alphabetically?

Comment: Check out the RS variable in awk, and some ideas in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061475/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-pattern/8062412#8062412

Comment: I don't mind using grep. Thanks

Comment: @Beta, I would like to use the original filename (test.csv or testsort.csv) and use a sequential counter for the resultant filename(s). Column# 2 could contain any number of different values (and not just 3 that I used in the example). Thanks

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question. How does `grep TRAINAMS testsort.csv > testsort_1.csv` grab you?

Comment: @Beta - I clarified my comment above. Thanks

Comment: wrt `Not sure if the sort is even required and if the above can be achieved without sorting.` - no, it's not, and yes, it's a common task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good move separating `sort` and `awk`.

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2 test.csv |awk -F, '!($2 in T) {T[$2]=++i} {print > ("testsort_" i ".csv")}'

$ tail -n +1 testsort*
==> testsort_1.csv <==
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,1221-ESD
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A101,PWR-120
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,PWR-120

==> testsort_2.csv <==
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A1,074-HD-SATA
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A15,102-55665

==> testsort_3.csv <==
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-20
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-21
WH_03,TRAINLON,UK-B3,101859
```

- `!($2 in T)`  - If the second field is not found in the indices of array `T`,
- `{T[$2]=++i}` - increment the counter and save the second field as an index.
- `{print}`     - print every line
- `> "file"`    - overwrite, redirect, and append output to file
- `("." i ".")` - concatenate "strings" and variable

Comment: If the file is sorted then you don't need to store all the $2 values in an array and map them to their output file number `!($2 in T) {T[$2]=++i}` all you need is `$2!=p{++i;p=$2}`

Comment: Thanks for the `tail -n +1 testsort*` idea to print file names and contents btw - much better than the shell loop with echos and cats I'd been using!

Comment: looks cool, but what if actual input has a million different values in 2nd column? You'll get a *too many open files* error in that case. And I didn't get the point of hashing second column with output file count in `T`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not sure if you need to sort that almost certainly means you don't and you just think it'd be useful for some reason plus you're just sorting on $2 and then splitting into different files based on the value of $2 so sorting is doing no good whatsoever.

All you actually need to do is:

```
awk -F, '{print > ($2".csv")}'
```

Look:

```
$ ls
test.csv

$ awk -F, '{print > ($2".csv")}' test.csv

$ ls
test.csv  TRAINAMS.csv  TRAINCLE.csv  TRAINLON.csv

$ tail -n +1 TRAIN*
==> TRAINAMS.csv <==
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,1221-ESD
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A101,PWR-120
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,PWR-120

==> TRAINCLE.csv <==
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A1,074-HD-SATA
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A15,102-55665

==> TRAINLON.csv <==
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-21
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-20
WH_03,TRAINLON,UK-B3,101859
```

If you got past about 20 output file names and weren't using GNU awk then you'd have to close() each one whenever $2 changes and use `>>` instead of `>` to append to them.

If for some reason you really do need to use the output file names from your question then that'd be:

```
awk -F, '!($2 in map){map[$2]="testsort_"++cnt".csv"} {print > map[$2]}' test.csv
```

Comment: That's almost not fair, but you are right. If you are outputting records based on a field to a filename also based on a field -- there is no need to sort first. Went right by me.

Comment: Could `awk -F, '{split ($1, a, "_"); print > ("testsort_" a[2] ".csv")}' file.csv` avoid storing the filenames, or would the cost of `split` be greater?

Comment: The split() would be slower since the other way is just a hash lookup while this is splitting a string at regexps and also that would generate files based on the unique value of the first field when the OP wants them based on the unique values in the 2nd field. I know they seem to go hand-in-hand in the example but idk in the real data if that'd always hold true.

Comment: Thanks Ed, the intent in generating the filename from the first field was simply the example output shown with `"testsort_1.csv", ...`

Comment: @Ed Morton: the () in ($2".csv") is for readability or has any other specific purpose? I removed the () and it behaves the same. thanks

Comment: @alphaGeek It's for portability. The meaning of an unparenthesized expression on the right side of input or output redirection is undefined by POSIX and so will produce different behavior in different awks. Specifically some awks will read `print > $2".csv"` as if you wrote `(print > $2)".csv"` and produce a syntax error. So it's required on some awks and always improves readability so just always parenthesize any expression on the right side of input or output redirection, e.g. `getline < ("foo"7)` or `print > ("foo"7)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a fairly simple fashion by keeping a counter for the filename and using `sprintf` to create the filename for each successive group of files. You use the `FNR` (file record number) to distinguish between the first and subsequent records.

For example:

```
$ sort -t, -k2 file.csv | 
awk -F, -v cnt=1 -v fn="testsort_1.csv" '
    FNR==1 {
        prev=$2
        print $0 > fn
    } 
    FNR>1 {
        if ($2!=prev) {
            cnt++
            fn=sprintf("%s_%d.csv", "testsort", cnt)
        }
        print $0 > fn
        prev=$2
    }'
```

(**note:** you set the initial filename as a variable to begin, and then create all subsequent filenames from your `cnt` (count) using `sprintf`. `prev` tracks the second field from the previous record. `fn` is the filename created by `sprintf` and the counter.)

A shorter version of the same script declaring `prev` as a variable initially, would be:

```
sort -t, -k2 file.csv | 
awk -F, -v cnt=0 -v prev="" '{
    if ($2!=prev) {
        cnt++
        fn = "testsort_" cnt ".csv"
        prev=$2
    }
    print $0 > fn 
}'
```

If you do not wish to have sequentially numbered files, but instead want the `"testsort_number.csv"` taken from the sorted records, look at [@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) now-deleted answer that provides an excelled (and shorter) solution in that regard. (I see you already have great answer)

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file.csv`, the following output files would be created:

```
$ for i in testsort_{1..3}.csv; do printf "\n%s\n" $i; cat $i; done

testsort_1.csv
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,1221-ESD
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A10,PWR-120
WH_01,TRAINAMS,A101,PWR-120

testsort_2.csv
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A1,074-HD-SATA
WH_02,TRAINCLE,A15,102-55665

testsort_3.csv
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-20
WH_03,TRAINLON,L10A3,3005-21
WH_03,TRAINLON,UK-B3,101859
```